# Android generate signed bundle or APK dialog shows unwanted project

Tags: android, dialog, bundle, generate

After upgrading to Android Studio 2021.2.1 Patch 1 (from 2020.3.1 Patch 4) when generating bundles (or APK) the list of modules has quadrupled, showing modules I don't have as seen on screenshot.

Every original module now comes with 3 extras, *.androidTest, *.main and *.unitTest !

Anyone know how to get rid of those ?

[image: Generate Signed Bundle Dialog]